# When community gives the bounty?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty

I saw on MSE some of the answers are awarded with a bounty of +50 by the community.

- Though that answer is not accepted by the OP.
- Though that answer is not that old.
- Those question are not seem that much hard.
- Those questions are not Favorited by multiple users.

I didn't see any of the above characteristics into those questions then also they are awarded with a bounty by community. So My question is:

When the community at MSE awards a bounty to an answer?

---

> **Update For The Clearance**
>
> 1. [Magento 1.9 get cart total based on site ID or site code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266803/magento-1-9-get-cart-total-based-on-site-id-or-site-code/267137#267137)
> 2. [not stored value in Mage::registry after admin session expire](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151778/not-stored-value-in-mageregistry-after-admin-session-expire/152003#152003)
> 3. [Magento 2 Ui Component resizeDefaultWidth not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179055/magento-2-ui-component-resizedefaultwidth-not-working/180377#180377)
> 4. [Magento 2 : Save date and MultiSelect field value added in Ui_Component](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220965/magento-2-save-date-and-multiselect-field-value-added-in-ui-component/222115#222115)
> 5. [Magento 2.2.4 - Modifying Cache configs via CLI or env.php not working when Opcache
>      Enabled](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225511/magento-2-2-4-modifying-cache-configs-via-cli-or-env-php-not-working-when-opca/225937#225937)
> 6. [Magento2 : Parent category load child category's product too](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235302/magento2-parent-category-load-child-categorys-product-too/237999#237999)
> 7. [Magento 2.2: Weird $_files array after image upload](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219907/magento-2-2-weird-files-array-after-image-upload/257711#257711)

You can refer the above given posts that are awarded with the bounties that is been awarded by the community

> Note: I have added these posts just for the example there is no any
>   indention to point out any one & their posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read more about how the bounty works: https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/bounty
But just to make it clear there is no "community magic bounty".
The bounty is offered by another user that wants to reward the person that answered a question, even if the question was not posted by the person that started the bounty. There is a chance that the answer did not solve the problem for the user that posted the question but it may have helped the person offering the bounty.

[Edit]

For answers like this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/267137/146

The bounty was started by the OP: https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/33043/mehar?tab=bounties
but the OP did not click on the "award bounty" button for the answer that has the bounty awarded.
The bounty was awarded automatically.
In the documentation link above there is this:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

Comment: See [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266803/magento-1-9-get-cart-total-based-on-site-id-or-site-code/267137#267137) here no one have offered any bounty to this question but still this answer got the bounty & when you hover on that +50 it is giving the name as offered by community

Comment: The concept that you have explained here thank you for that but I know this system but I observed something different then this behavior so that's the reason I asked the question here

Comment: There are so many your own post that is been awarded by the bounties & that is been provided by the community Please see my updated sections in the question for example & clearance

Comment: I've updated my answer with additional info

Comment: Got it thanks for the information! I was not aware of this system!